# How to send poactivate message to all users interact with Bot via Facebook Messager

Tags: azure, botframework

I created a Facebook chatbot to send poactivate message based on this sample https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-proactiveMessages. But I found it only works with the latest user interact with the Bot via Facebook Messager. I want to send the message to all users who have been interactive with bot. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you keep their addresses? (a part of the session object)

Comment: Based on above sample, I save the session.message.address to a variable in user data such as sessions.user.address